# Show English when there is no translation

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n

I have a website for a client, with more than 5 languages (`bg`, `en`, `ru`, `ch`, `de`, `it` ...). The client wants to add a news section but the news should be only in `en` or `ch` and if the user selects a language which is different then `en` or `ch`, `en` should be shown.

Is it possible when you add a content with English language, automatically translations for all other languages to be created instead of adding one by one the translations via translate menu entry?

Comment: We love to help you but this question unfortunately is way too broad. There are at least 3 very different (and each quite complex) questions in it. Try to narrow down your problem to one question and update your question accordingly. Important for us also is to see what you've tried yourself so far and where exactly you are stuck. Thank you!

Comment: Mmm.. long time ago there was an option "When translation is missing, show content in default language" which I am looking for...

Comment: Right, this has been dropped from the 7.x version of the `i18n` module. See https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n/issues/1238138

Comment: Yes I read this already, but there is nothing that can help me there. thanks

Comment: For the last remaining question now we still need to know what you've tried so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I do not know what I can try to achieve this, otherwise I will not ask. Looks like the only solution I see is to force the client to do manually dummy translations for all languages every time. Thanks for your time

Comment: Maybe google for "drupal 7 create translation programmatically" and pick one, try to build that and then you may come back when something's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Language fallback](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_fallback) module

I haven't tried this module but it seems to do what you're asking for. You can edit bg, de, it etc languages and set English as the fallback.

Drupal 8 also has one extra module for this: [Entity Language Fallback](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_language_fallback)

### Automate with Rules

You could probably come up with a Rule that automatically saves translation nodes of an English node under certain circumstances, with some custom code.

### Quickly fill in translations

If you can't do custom code for what ever reason, you could enable **[Synchronize translations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279460)** (which is a submodule of i18n) on your Content types. This way when you go to translate other languages you'd already have the English text filled in, images kept etc so you just Save the node and see English text on an Italian node.

Comment: thanks, I am using Synchronize translations already and it works as you write - when you add a translation, it by default is in English. But what I want to achieve is to skip all the steps of adding translation and saving for 9+ languages when the translations will be only for 2 of the languages.. If it is only one language from 9 I can exclude translations and all the content will be only once added in English for example and everything will be ok. But with 2 of 9 becomes a bit complicated..

Comment: Have you tried the Language fallback module? It gives you the behavior you want without any extra saving.